# Sum calculation in a Form

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a form that outputs to a HTML Document. The user as some options which affect the discount to be applied. I have the Subtotal Working but the Discount and Grand total don't work properly. The Discount will output some values but others don't display.

The grand total only displays as NaN.

I've tried to use other methods of approach to calculate the sums but not had any luck

```
//The proceeding code calculated the sum based on the users selections

    //Variable that Displays the SubTotal before discount is applied
    var eltableSub = document.getElementById("tableSub")
    if (PropertyUsage == "Residential")
        eltableSub.textContent = "£ " + (90 * NumberOfRooms).toFixed(2);
    if (PropertyUsage == "Business")
        eltableSub.textContent = "£ " + (150 * NumberOfRooms).toFixed(2);
    //Variable that displays the discount
    var elDiscount = document.getElementById("tableDiscount")
        if (NumberOfRooms  <=5 & PropertyUsage == "Residential")
            elDiscount.textContent = '£ ' + (NumberOfRooms * 90).toFixed(2) + " No Discount applied"
        if ((NumberOfRooms >=6 & NumberOfRooms <=9) & PropertyUsage == "Residential")
            elDiscount.textContent = '£ ' + ((NumberOfRooms * 90) / 100 * 10).toFixed(2) + " (10%)"
        if ((NumberOfRooms >=10 & PropertyUsage == "Residential"))
            elDiscount.textContent = '£ ' + ((NumberOfRooms * 90) / 100 * 15).toFixed(2) + " (15%)"
        if  (NumberOfRooms  <=5 & PropertyUsage == "Business")
            elDiscount.textContent = '£ ' + (NumberOfRooms * 150).toFixed(2) + " No Discount applied"
        if ((NumberOfRooms >=6 & NumberOfRooms <=9) & PropertyUsage == "business")
            elDiscount.textContent = '£ ' + ((NumberOfRooms * 150) / 100 * 10).toFixed(2) + " (10%)"
        if  (NumberOfRooms >=10 & PropertyUsage == "Business")
            elDiscount.textContent = '£ ' + ((NumberOfRooms * 150) / 100 * 15).toFixed(2) + " (15%)" // Working!!!!

    // Variable that Displays the Total based on the number of rooms and the applicable discount
    var elTableTotal = document.getElementById('tableTotal')


} 

function ShowSum(){
var Summary = document.getElementById("SummaryTable")
Summary.style.display="block";
}
```

The expected output should display the SubTotal, Discount(As a value and string representation) and the GrandTotal

Comment: Totally unrelated, but the amount of duplicated logic and same-level `if` statements makes this difficult to reason about (and debug).

Comment: I agree Dave but I haven't been shown a better way to structure it to achieve the result.

Comment: if you are getting NaN You need to convert the inputs to numeric int or float, check the type of NumberOfRooms

Comment: *Very* roughly: https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/74befeb5f89bc6a81d55f9b3471a9238 I'd argue that not being *shown* cleaner code isn't really a reason.